# Age Format - Year and Month

Tags: mysql, datediff

I am trying to figure out how to convert the Student Age into Age + Months.  So for example, if a Student's Birthdate was 1/1/2000 then the Student Age would appear as:  16 and 6 Months

I am able to script the query so that the Student Age appears as a whole number, but am not sure how to then include the months.  What do I need to change?

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[RP_Student_Attendance] (@perf_code varchar(10))
as

-- set @perf_code = '3496A'

SELECT
    i.short_name, 
    i.text1 as perf_desc, 
    i.text2 perf_dates, 
    i.text3 perf_times,
    p.perf_no, 
    h.[Role], 
    h.customer_no,
    c.sex, b.birthday, 
    g.grade_level, 
    --(DATEDIFF(yy,b.birthday,GETDATE())) as student_age, 
    student_age = CASE

WHEN dateadd(year, datediff (year, b.birthday, GETDATE()),b.birthday) > GETDATE()
THEN datediff (year, b.birthday, GETDATE()) - 1
ELSE datediff (year, b.birthday, GETDATE())end,
    c.fname + ' ' + c.lname as student_name

FROM T_INVENTORY i
JOIN T_PERF p on i.inv_no = p.perf_no
JOIN T_TICKET_HISTORY h on p.perf_no = h.perf_no and [Role] = 4
JOIN T_CUSTOMER c on h.customer_no = c.customer_no 
LEFT JOIN (select customer_no, key_value as birthday from TX_CUST_KEYWORD where keyword_no = 1) b on c.customer_no = b.customer_no
LEFT JOIN (select customer_no, key_value as grade_level from TX_CUST_KEYWORD where keyword_no = 428) g on c.customer_no = g.customer_no
WHERE p.perf_code = @perf_code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the precision, this gets you in the ball park:

```
mysql> select floor(datediff(now(), '2000-01-01') / 365) as years, ceil(mod(datediff(now(), '2000-01-01'), 365) / 30) as months;
+-------+--------+
| years | months |
+-------+--------+
|    16 |      6 |
+-------+--------+
```

I repeat, use only *if you don't care about the precision*. This could easy report "7" months when it's actually "6".